# Logstash-logback-encoder: Using StructuredArguments without formatting in the message?

Tags: logstash, slf4j, logstash-logback-encoder

I wonder what the best practices are with using StructuredArguments inside logging calls when using logstash-logback-encoder to log in JSON format.

I want to log some structured arguments in separate fields, but I **don't** want to format these arguments into the literal string message.

If I write my log lines like this, everything works fine as I want to, but both my IntelliJ IDEA and Sonarqube static code analysis considers this problematic issues:

```
log.info("Query executed successfully!", StructuredArguments.value("hits", result.getHits()));
(or more concise)
log.info("Query executed successfully!", v("hits", result.getHits()));
```

IntelliJ warns this on this line:

> more arguments provided (1) than placeholders specified (0)

How can I avoid this? Of course I can silence the warnings and add exceptions for them, but I wonder if that is a best practice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't want to include the data inside the log message, and want to avoid the static analysis warnings, use `Markers` instead of `StructuredArguments`:

```java
import net.logstash.logback.marker.Markers;

log.info(Markers.append("hits", result.getHits()), "Query executed successfully!");
```

See [here](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder/tree/2e98d6c74d3e19bfd6780dfe593e8b020ed7d10e#event-specific-custom-fields) for more details.